# Failed to install Twint on Windows

Tags: installation, twitter, pip, twint

I could not install twint on command prompt. I tried with pip install twint and the following error message came up:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: cchardet
  Building wheel for cchardet (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      cythonize: ['src/cchardet\\_cchardet.pyx']
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cchardet
      copying src\cchardet\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cchardet
      copying src\cchardet\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cchardet
      running build_ext
      building 'cchardet._cchardet' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cchardet
  Running setup.py clean for cchardet
Failed to build cchardet
Installing collected packages: cchardet, beautifulsoup4, aiohttp-socks, aiodns, twint
  Running setup.py install for cchardet ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for cchardet did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      cythonize: ['src/cchardet\\_cchardet.pyx']
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cchardet
      copying src\cchardet\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cchardet
      copying src\cchardet\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cchardet
      running build_ext
      building 'cchardet._cchardet' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> cchardet

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

C:\Users\Yannik>
```

Comment: Did you notice `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+or+greater+is+required